# Arranging PDFs within A File

Tags: macbook-pro, finder

I'm trying to organize photos I've taken in to subfolders within a master PHOTO file.  I created a file on my desktop and then drag and dropped images from my Photo library in to that master folder.  Once I populated that folder with about 20 images, I created subfolders within the master Photo file.  Yet, I could not drag and drop those recently moved images from the master folder in to the sub folders.  As you can tell, I'm just barely above techno-boob when it comes to these things...

I have moved several pdfs from one file to another and then created sub folders to organize.  I can't move the pdfs within the master folder to the sub-folders.  I try to drag and drop and all it does is expand the image as a preview.

Comment: Can you add some details about what you are trying to do? Are you working in Finder, in Preview.app or somewhere else? With "as a preview", do you mean QuickLook (what you get if you press the Space bar on a file in Finder) or something else? Is the problem just with PDFs or with all file types? Please edit your question to provide more information, adding a screenshot might also help to understand the issue better.

Comment: I cannot drag and drop several pdfs that sit within a folder I created to a series of sub folders.  I'm used to drag and dropping but in this instance, clicking on the pdf to "grab" it only expands the thumbnail but it won't budge.  So sitting within my master Photo folder are 20 jpg.s and 5 sub folders.  How do I move these jpg.s?

Comment: Please add a screenshot. It's difficult to understand where/in which application you are doing what, so a picture might be faster in explaining what you are seeing than trying to get the names of the things right.

Comment: I took a screen shot of the dilemma yet ironically, I don't know how to embed that screen shot within this dialog.  I thought possibly of dragging and dropping it within the "Add Comment" window and of course that did not work... suggestions?

Comment: Click on edit below the question, then on the icon with the picture on top of the edit window

Answer (score 1):

Your file folders in Finder have only basic sorting options.

You would need to edit the names of the files so they sort alphabetically or by date or by size if you want to use Finder to sort and organize works.

Depending on what you're doing, there might be a general purpose tool like Evernote or [Yojimbo](http://www.barebones.com/products/Yojimbo/) to help you organize and catalog PDF files. Apple's iBooks also might be worth looking at, but it's organizational skills are less sophisticated than the other two apps I mentioned first.